# Check arraylist property if it true for all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have the following Javascript array of objects ,I need to check output property if it true for all objects , if output true for all object return true else return false,Can anyone help me to implement that?

```
 var array=[{"id":100,"output":true},{"id":200,"output":true}]
```

updates

I have try this code but it execute print if just one output is  true not all output

```
function check(){
     var data=[{"id":100,"output":false},{"id":200,"output":true}]
     data.every(function (e) {
         if(e.checked===true){
             console.log("print something")
        }
       });
 }
```

what is the wrong in code?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function

```js
var array = [{"id":100,"output":true},{"id":200,"output":true}]

var istrue = array.every( obj => obj.output === true );

console.log(istrue)
```

In ES5

```
array.every( function(obj) { return obj.output === true });
```

Note that this does strict checking against the boolean `true`, not just any truthy value

Comment: As much as I dislike people answering homework-y questions, this answer is very useful.

Comment: That doesn't work because you changed the entire code to something else? Here -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/920saudh/